# How to use EnumWindows to get only actual application windows?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I want to get all Windows that I could take a screenshot, application windows. I am trying to use `EnumWindows`.

```
public delegate bool CallBackPtr(IntPtr hwnd, int lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int EnumWindows(CallBackPtr callPtr, int lPar);

public static List<IntPtr> EnumWindows()
{
    var result = new List<IntPtr>();

    EnumWindows(new User32.CallBackPtr((hwnd, lParam) =>
    {
        result.Add(hwnd);
        return true;
    }), 0);

    return result;
}
```

However this is returning more Windows than I expect, such as:

[image: tooltip]

[image: tooltip]

[image: blackthing]

I want to grab only Windows like Visual Studio, Skype, Explorer, Chrome...

Should I be using another method? Or how do I check if it is a window I want to grab?

Comment: As you have handles of windows try to filter them by style. Explore [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633584(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps checking the window's style for a title bar will do what you want:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

static bool IsAppWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    int style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, -16); // GWL_STYLE

    // check for WS_VISIBLE and WS_CAPTION flags
    // (that the window is visible and has a title bar)
    return (style & 0x10C00000) == 0x10C00000;
}
```

But this won't work for some of the fancier apps which are fully custom drawn.

Comment: It filtered quit a lot, but there are still lots of black windows... http://imgur.com/5AE9ekd

Comment: Perhaps check for `WS_VISIBLE` (`0x10000000`) as well.

Comment: Combining both conditions worked exactly as I was expecting. Thank you.

Comment: This method filters out all metro apps. The Windows 10 calculator is one of the windows that will be filtered out using this method. All Microsoft Edge windows will be filtered out as well.